# using xargs to cd to a directory

Tags: unix, xargs

Feeling like an idiot right now. Why does this not work?

```
echo "/some/directory/path" | xargs -n1 cd
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The pipe runs xargs in a subprocess, and xargs runs cd in a subprocess. Changes in a subprocess do not get propagated to the parent process.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thanks for helping a Unix noob.

Comment: You can get the effect you want by using back-quotes: `cd \`echo "/some/directory/path" | cut -d\  -f1\``  (Note that I added 'cut' to split on spaces and grab the first item the way xargs does)

Comment: Actually, `xargs` can't run `cd` since it's, of necessity, a shell builtin and `xargs` can only run free-standing executables. What you said is true about subprocesses, however.

Comment: /usr/bin/cd is definitely a Unix free standing documented command, at least on Solaris.

Comment: Using @Slartibartfast for auto-generated paths: ``cd `port file libcudd | sed -e 's/\/Portfile//'` `` (usually long ones you don't want to handle manually, like this MacPorts Portfile location).

Comment: I got here because I wanted to change the path before cd-ing into it in the current shell, and found that I can do that using a bash function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/1386750

Answer (score 34):

The command `cd` is a built-in because the information about the current directory is tied to a process and only shell built-in can change current directory of the running shell.

There are two problems with your code:

1. `xargs` cannot run `cd` because `cd` is a built-in command and `xargs` can run only executable files.
2. Even if you run `cd` in a sub-process called from `xargs`, it will not have any effect on the parent process as explained above.

The solution is to run a sub-shell, inside it run `cd` and then you can execute commands in the new current directory.

```
ls | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd "$0" && pwd && ls'
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do `ls | xargs ...` in this example. It should be passing in the value for `$0`, like `echo "/some/directory/path" | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd "$0" && pwd && ls'`

Comment: IMO a better solution would be :   ls | xargs -L 1 -I @@ bash -c 'cd @@ && pwd && ls'

Comment: This should be the accepted answer